# Unity OnControllerColliderHit triggered multiple times in one frame

Tags: unity

```
private void Update()
{
     Debug.Log("### " + CollisionFlags);
     CollisionFlags = CharacterController.Move(moveAmount);
}

private void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
{
    Debug.Log("### OnControllerColliderHit " + hit.gameObject.name);
}
```

the characterController is heading down to plane and
I called characterController move function in update() and i expect the result is like

"None"

"OnControllerColliderHit Cube (2)"

"Below"

"OnControllerColliderHit Cube (2)"

but result is

"None"

"OnControllerColliderHit Cube (2)"

"OnControllerColliderHit Cube (2)"

"OnControllerColliderHit Cube (2)"

"OnControllerColliderHit Cube (2)"

... 12 times.

"Below"

Why OnControllerColliderHit triggered 12 times in one frame?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because CharacterController performs multiple sub-movements on each `Move()` call, this can trigger multiple collisions.

You can get the first collision by setting a variable before each Move() and resetting in inside OnControllerColliderHit like this:

```
bool first;
void Update(){
    first = true;
    CharacterController.Move(moveAmount);
}

void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit){
    if(first){
        // do stuff
        first = false;
    }
    else{
        // ignore other collisions
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you mean it called more if characterController move further in one frame?

Comment: it's not about frames, it's about each Move() call, whenever you call Move(), the CharacterController may (or may not) perform multiple steps in order to get where you want it to. This is done maybe to ensure proper collision checks (I'm guessing). But each of those sub-steps might trigger a collision and thus call OnControllerColliderHit(). With this code, if you want to get only the first collision everytime you call Move() you will have to reset your variable before calling it.

Comment: Another explanation could be that the call to Move command is given in `Update`, but the actual movement and the `OnCollision*` events they cause are called during the `FixedUpdate` phase of the engine. Updates and FixedUpdates aren't synchronized with each other. You might have multiple of one happen before the next of the other happens.

Comment: @Philipp I'm not sure that Move() gets called inside FixedUpdate, because the position updates instantly, so I guess that it's calculated immediately.

Comment: @Xriuk That would depend on how that method is implemented in the class CharacterController. Perhaps they are using the standard one, but it could just as well be a self-programmed one.